Using tlast in AXI-Streaming interface with fixed sized packets
I am trying to understand the proper use of the tlast intended by the AMBA AXI Stream designers. The tlast can be used to mark the end of a packet on a streaming interface.
If it is known that all packets on streaming interface must be N words and then the tready from data sink can be deasserted, is it any benefit to use the tlast? Doing so seems redundant.

From searching some Xilinx documentation TLAST can be redundant in some cases:

The AXI4-Stream Interface section of Soft-Decision FEC Integrated Block LogiCORE IP Product Guide (PG256) contains the following, which says tlast is redundant as far as that core is concerned and is ignored:

Use of TLAST
The core always produces tlast signals on all output channels; however the sizes of input packets are always either fixed or given explicitly using associated control information. Hence the tlast on input channels is actually redundant; requiring a source to provide a suitable tlast could hinder interoperability. Therefore the core has been specifically designed to ignore tlast inputs for packet delineation and use internal knowledge of packet size instead.


The Vector Data Example section of Vivado Design Suite AXI Reference Guide has the following:


Slaves that do not require TLAST to identify packet boundaries.
Some slave channels have an internal expectation of what size packets are required. For example, an FFT input packet size is always the same as the transform size. In these cases, TLAST would represent redundant information and also potentially introduce ambiguity into packet sizing (for example: what should an N-point FFT do when presented with an N-1 sample input packet.)
To prevent this ambiguity, many Xilinx IP cores are designed to ignore TLAST on slave channels, and to use the explicit packet sizing information available to them.
In these situations the core uses the required number of AXI transfers it is expecting regardless of TLAST. This typically greatly aides interoperability as the master and slave are not required to agree on when TLAST must be asserted.
For example, consider an FIR followed by an N-point FFT. The FIR is a stream-based core and cannot natively generate a stream with TLAST asserted every N transfers.
If the FFT is designed to ignore the incoming TLAST this is not an issue, and the system functions as expected. However, if the FFT did require TLAST, an intermediate “re-framing” core would be required to introduce the required signalling.





This answer doesn't give a single benefit to using TLAST, but rather it depends upon the subsystems in use.
